# Different behaviours when suspending

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management

I always suspend my laptop in two different ways:

- Clicking "suspend" on the right top corner.
- Using the command line `sudo pm-suspend`.

Depending on how I do it, the bahaviour is different. The first way, it requires the password to wake up from suspend, but if I suspend from Terminal, it doesn't ask me for password while waking up from suspend. Is this one the "normal" behaviour? Can I get the laptop asking me the password, even if I suspend from Terminal?

Answer (score 0):

If you suspend using `sudo pm-suspend` it will NOT block your session while you're using GUI, which is insecure. so you'll need to do it from panel or you can do it using

`sudo pmi action suspend`

For that you nee to install powermanagement-interface

```
sudo apt-get install powermanagement-interface
```

and suspend using

```
sudo pmi action suspend
```

Comment: Well, the issue is not about the panel but the terminal. I have by default that the shell doesn't ask me for password when using sudo. What I meant is that, when I suspend from command line and then resume the laptop, it doesn's ask for password (it asks for it if I suspend from panel).

Comment: Sorry for my English. I get this error message: `Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Hal was not provided by any .service files`